# Handlebars - Set ID of Object created with {{each}} Helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Let's say I have a number of objects in a list, and I want to create `<tr/>` elements in a `<table/>` from this objects. I created an `Ember.View` like this:

```
App.TableRowItem = Ember.View.extend({
  classNames: ['list-row'],
  templateName: 'admin/things/tableRow',
  showActionRow: function() {},
  edit: function() {},
  save: function() {},
  delete: function() {}
});
```

Now, I want to generate a row item for each object in my retrieved list, in a Handlebars template, like this:

```
<table id="someTable">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Head1</th><th>Head2</th><th>Head3</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{# each thing in controller.things}}
      {{log thing}}
      {{view App.TableRowItem contentBinding="thing" id="thing.id"}}
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and I expect it to do an output wich creates an `id` tag for each element with the id of `this.id`, but instead I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Attempted to register a view with an id already in use: this.id
```

What am I doing wrong? If I dont set the `id` within the `{{view}}` helper, I get the same message as above, but it moans about the `id already in use: null`...

---

## UPDATE:

As I wasn't able to solve the problem with an `idBinding` I tried the following solution in my `App.TableRowItem` view:

```
App.TableRowItem = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'tr',
  templateName: 'admin/things/tableRow',

  // this is new!
  init: function() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ ) {
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }

    this.set('elementId', text);
  }
});
```

and now I don't see any error, BUT I see that there is not only the `<tr/>` from the template (`admin/things/tableRow`), but also a `<div/>` element which seems to be a representation of my `App.TableRowItem` without any content!?

While debugging `this.$()` gives me an empty `<tr id="1fFxV" class="ember-view"></tr>` and the `tableRow` template is reachable through `this.$().closest('tr').next()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `this` to refer to the item in the loop, you need to change your `{{#each}}` format:

```
{{#each controller.things}}
  <!-- here the value of `this` is each item in the loop -->
{{/each}}
```

The way your `{{each}}` is constructed, `this` does not refer to the item but to the controller.

```
{{#each thing in controller.things}}
  <!-- to reference every item you need to use `thing` instead of `this` -->
{{/each}}
```

So this would work:

```
{{#each thing in controller.things}}
  {{view App.TableRowItem contentBinding="thing" idBinding="thing.id"}}
{{/each}}
```

or this:

```
{{#each controller.things}}
  {{view App.TableRowItem contentBinding="this" idBinding="id"}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your solutions! unfortunately the `idBinding` doesn't seem to work - I keep getting the error `id already in use: null` over and over again. just for clearing things out: I don't even care which `id` the element has, I just want to get rid of the error :)

Comment: It seems things are getting more complicated than they should be.  Here's a working fiddle that should help you: http://jsfiddle.net/ztWEJ/

Comment: thanks a lot for the fiddle - I think I'll follow this direction to not get too complicated just for a table :)

Answer (score 2):

I have done similar. My controller looked like this:

```
App.ExampleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  id: function() {
    var id = this.get('id');
    return id;
  }.property('id')
});
```

In my view looked like this:

```
{{#each item in items }}
  <div class="exampleItem" {{bindAttr id="item.id"}}>
    Code comes here..
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the HTML. I think you'll find you're setting the elementId to the string "this.id", if you want to bind values you have to use the binding.

However, if you try and use elementIdBinding="this.id" you will get an error thrown, as an id can not be modified once the element is created as Ember uses IDs for internal booking.

Pretty much it's not worth trying to set custom ID's inside collections and try to solve your issue without requiring specific IDs

Comment: thanks a lot - in fact, I don't even care about the `id`, but I keep seeing the error `...id already in use: null` if I don't set any ID...